# How to replicate this mpv socat command but as a PHP 8.2 cURL request?

Tags: php, linux, curl, unix-socket, mpv

I'm trying to use mpv's API. I have followed this: https://mpv.io/manual/master/#json-ipc

1. I started mpv with: `mpv /path/to/file.mkv --input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`.
2. I ran `echo '{ "command": ["get_property", "playback-time"] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket` in a terminal, and it works (returns JSON output).

Now I have spent countless hours not being able to replicate this as PHP 8.2 cURL code. This is only the latest out of numerous different variations I've tried. Yes, I've tried using it without the `CURLOPT_URL`, with and without JSON encoding, and just about every "obvious" thing that somebody could suggest. None of them work.

```
$POST_data =
[
    'command'   => [ "get_property", "playback-time" ]
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '/tmp/mpvsocket');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH, '/tmp/mpvsocket');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($POST_data));
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ABSTRACT_UNIX_SOCKET, '/tmp/mpvsocket');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($response);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

The output is:

```
* Closing connection -1
bool(false)
string(0) ""
```

Context: Debian Linux. PHP 8.2.

I have no problems making HTTP(S) requests, even to localhost, from the same kind of code. It seems to only be a problem when "Unix sockets" are involved. But PHP's cURL long since supports this, so it doesn't make any sense. Yes, I've checked so that `/tmp/mpvsocket` exists.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Where did you read that cURL supports the IPC protocol? I don't see it here: https://curl.se/

Comment: I'd guess you'd be more likely to get results using plain sockets in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: Frankly not sure what IPC is... Isn't `CURLOPT_UNIX_SOCKET_PATH` implying that it supports Unix sockets (which it also explicitly states somewhere that I can't find it now)?

Comment: @ADyson I asked an AI to make a working PHP example of that socat command, and it gave a sockets-based answer, but it also doesn't work.

Comment: You can pipe data via a unix socket, but then the actual message you send has to conform to the protocol on top. The link you gave says that you have to control the mpv device using JSON IPC protocol

Comment: and CURLOPT_POST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS make zero sense when you're not sending a HTTP request (as per https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). Not sure the URL makes much sense either.

Comment: As for socat, there's a usage example right there in the documentation so I doubt you need AI (which, remember, just pulls things off the internet it thinks would look plausible when placed next to each other...it cannot (yet) actually write and understand code in a meaningful way) for that.

Comment: I suspect the PHP code shown in the question at  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18408364/5947043 or maybe this little library: https://github.com/lifo101/php-ipc might be useful to you

Comment: @ADyson What do you mean by "there's a usage example right there in the documentation"?

Comment: https://mpv.io/manual/master/#socat-example

Comment: @ADyson I don't understand what you mean by that first SO link, and the library in the second URL hasn't been updated for a decade... stone dead.

Comment: @ADyson You cannot have read my question because I literally show that command as an example of something that works, asking how to replicate it in PHP...

Comment: Well why not just use `exec` or `shell_exec` in PHP to run a command that you know can work, that was kind of my point. Get PHP to build the socat command string, including the data you want to string, and then execute it. It's one option.

Comment: `the library in the second URL hasn't been updated for a decade`...doesn't necessarily mean it won't work. The protocol definition hasn't changed either AFAIK. There aren't a whole lot of choices out there if you want a pure PHP implementation, from my bit of research. Have you found any others?? At the very least it's a foundation you could build on - if the project's dead, and you need it, take the code and fork it, and fix up any issues. Probably better than starting from scratch.

Comment: `I don't understand what you mean by that first SO link`...I mean the bit of PHP code that the asker posted (which if you read the rest of the post seems to work, the issue was in the Go code) showing how to read and write from a UNIX socket using the PHP socket library.

Comment: Ignore my last comment (which I now deleted to avoid confusion). When restarting another instance of mpv, it worked. But I still don't like using the socat command through `shell_exec` etc., because it breaks cross-platformness... But then again, I've permanently dropped Windows anyway, so...

Comment: One way to get it working in Windows might be to use WSL, but if you're not worried about Windows support then it's less of an issue.